# Ruby Multidimensional Array - Remove duplicate in first position, add number in second position

Tags: arrays, ruby

For this array:

```
items = [[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2], [48, 2], [207, 2], [46, 2],
 [60, 2], [280, 2], [207, 1], [48, 1], [112, 1], [60, 1], [207, 1], [112, 1],
 [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [278, 1], [46, 1],
 [48, 1], [279, 1], [207, 1]]
```

I want to combine common numbers in the first positions of each sub-array, and add the numbers in the second positions together.

For instance, you'll see the first four sub-arrays here are: `[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2]`

This would become: `[60,6], [276,4]` and so on.

Comment: Any specific code you have tried, post it

Comment: Thanks for responding @Bijendra. I've been knocking around ideas for a little while now, but don't have any code as of yet...

Comment: I assume that if the array were `[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3]]` would you want to return [[1,6],[2,1]], not [[1,3],[2,1],[1,3]]. Correct?

Comment: Correct @CarySwoveland. I would expect to see ```[[1,6],[2,1]]```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
items.
  group_by {|i| i[0]}.
  map{|key, value| [key,value.inject(0){|sum, x| sum + x[1]}]}
```

Firstly, use [group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) to create a hash whose keys is the first element of each array. So we have

```
{
 60=>[[60, 3], [60, 3], [60, 2], [60, 1]],
 276=>[[276, 2], [276, 2], [276, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1]],
 48=>[[48, 2], [48, 1], [48, 1], [48, 1], [48, 1]],
 207=>[[207, 2], [207, 1], [207, 1], [207, 1]],
 46=>[[46, 2], [46, 1]],
 280=>[[280, 2]],
 112=>[[112, 1], [112, 1]],
 278=>[[278, 1]],
 279=>[[279, 1]]
}
```

Then to create the desired result, using [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map) method to loop the hash. To calculate total value for each key, using [inject](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) method to sum all second value of each array

```
[[60, 3], [60, 3], [60, 2], [60, 1]].inject(0) {|sum, x| sum + x[1]} #value is 9
```

Comment: You are a genius. This is perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: This could be improved with some explanatory text describing what each part does. When writing an answer, keep in mind that readers of all skill levels will find it.

Comment: The `group_by` can also be expressed as `group_by(&:first)` and a more concise `map` might be `map { |key, values| [key, values.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }`

Comment: Super @Long Nguyen

Answer (score 8):

You could use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

> Iterates the given block for each element with an arbitrary object
>   given, and returns the initially given object.

```
items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|a, h| h[a[0]] += a[1]}.to_a
# => [[60, 9], [276, 8], [48, 6], [207, 5], [46, 3], [280, 2],
#     [112, 2], [278, 1], [279, 1]]
```

From Stefen's comment

The Array passed to the block can be decomposed like this

```
items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(k,v), h| h[k] += v}.to_a
```

Comment: You can decompose the sub-arrays via `{ |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }`

Comment: @Stefan, yes, thats better.

Comment: This is excellent @Santhosh. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to group, map and inject for this data structure.

```
items = [[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2], [48, 2], [207, 2], [46, 2],
 [60, 2], [280, 2], [207, 1], [48, 1], [112, 1], [60, 1], [207, 1], [112, 1],
 [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [278, 1], [46, 1],
 [48, 1], [279, 1], [207, 1]]

# Provide a default value of 0 for all created entries in the hash.
# This saves us from having to conditionally set undefined entries to 0
# http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html
accumulator = Hash.new(0) # Thanks Eric!

# using reduce lets us perform the grouping and adding in one pass.
# as each  item is passed in, we define a member on our accumulator
# for the first number in the pair, and add the value of the second
# number in the pair to our member.
# http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce
output = items.reduce(accumulator) do |memo, item|
  memo[item[0]] = memo[item[0]] + item[1]
  memo
end

# Finally, convert the hash to an array
output.to_a

# => [[60, 9], [276, 8], [48, 6], [207, 5], [46, 3], [280, 2], [112, 2], [278, 1], [279, 1]]
```

Comment: You can also write `Hash.new(0)`.

Comment: Good answer, but "no need to group,..." is, imo, the wrong emphasis. There is no best way of solving this problem, just different ways.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for.

Answer (score 4):

```
items.group_by(&:shift).map{|k,v| [k,v.flatten.inject(:+)]}.to_h
```

But in real code that others should understand I would split it up into two lines and use this approach:

```
result = Hash.new(0)
items.each{|key,value| result[key] += value}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but `shift` will also alter `items`.

Comment: Really? Cannot get it to produce correct values. Could you show the entire code?

Answer (score 3):

Just to have an alternative, for fun, and play with the language:

```
items.inject([]) { |arr, el| arr[el[0]] = [el[0], (arr[el[0]] || [_, 0])[1] + el[1]]; arr }.compact
```

Can this be more cryptic?

```
items.inject([]) { |arr, el|
  arr[el[0]] = [el[0], (arr[el[0]] || [_, 0])[1] + el[1]]
  arr
}.compact
```

The `#inject` method starts with an empty array and adds elements as it traverses `items`. Each element `el` from `items` is placed at its index in `arr`. Thus, the first element `[60, 3]` will be placed at index 60 (a lot of holes) as `[60, 3]`.

Note the form of each entry in `arr`: `[el[0], (arr[el[0]] || [_, 0])[1] + el[1]]`. This says that the first element is the common value, and the second element adds up, initialized at 0.

This solution creates an array with a lot of holes. The `compact` method removes all holes.

I cannot recommend this solution, except as an exercise with the language.

---

And for some fun, a few answers coming in as I typed, so time for (unfair and non-scientific) comparisons:

```
require 'benchmark'

items = [[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2], [48, 2], [207, 2], [46, 2],
  [60, 2], [280, 2], [207, 1], [48, 1], [112, 1], [60, 1], [207, 1], [112, 1],
  [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [278, 1], [46, 1],
  [48, 1], [279, 1], [207, 1]]

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report(:long) { items.group_by {|i| i[0]}.map{|key, value|     [key,value.inject(0){|sum, x| sum + x[1]}]} }
  x.report(:randym) { items.reduce(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 0 }) { |memo, item| memo[item[0]] = memo[item[0]] + item[1]; memo }.to_a }
  x.report(:eric) { items.inject([]) { |arr, el| arr[el[0]] = [el[0], (arr[el[0]] || [0, 0])[1] + el[1]]; arr  }.compact }
end
```

Some outputs:

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
long     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000016)
randym   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000014)
eric     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
--------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

             user     system      total        real
long     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
randym   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
eric     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)


Rehearsal ------------------------------------------
long     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000024)
randym   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000014)
eric     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
--------------------------------- total: 0.000000sec

             user     system      total        real
long     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
randym   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
eric     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000014)
```

My cryptic and unmaintainable can be best or worse. Long's and Randym's are stable.

A final note, just in case: Subtracting the arrays returned by each solution allows to check that we all get the same results :-)

Comment: I would expect a larger data set would give us a better understanding of the performance metrics here. So much of Ruby's performance relates to object creation and garbage collection.

Comment: Sure. The above is just for fun and to show what can easily be done with the language and its standard library.

Comment: Wow that is fascinating

Comment: Thank you for documenting all of these benchmarks @EricPlaton. This is really interesting.

Comment: Cheers, that was fun question, and quite a few people enjoyed it apparently :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another look at performance with each_with_object included.
Looks like Santhosh is the winner.

```
require 'benchmark'

items = [[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2], [48, 2], [207, 2], [46, 2],
  [60, 2], [280, 2], [207, 1], [48, 1], [112, 1], [60, 1], [207, 1], [112, 1],
  [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [278, 1], [46, 1],
  [48, 1], [279, 1], [207, 1]]

20.times { items.concat items }

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report(:long) { items.group_by {|i| i[0]}.map{|key, value|     [key,value.inject(0){|sum, x| sum + x[1]}]} }
  x.report(:randym) { items.reduce(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = 0 }) { |memo, item| memo[item[0]] = memo[item[0]] + item[1]; memo }.to_a }
  x.report(:eric) { items.inject([]) { |arr, el| arr[el[0]] = [el[0], (arr[el[0]] || [0, 0])[1] + el[1]]; arr  }.compact }
  x.report(:santhosh) { (items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|a, h| h[a[0]] += a[1]  }).to_a }
end

Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
long       7.130000   0.740000   7.870000 (  8.464277)
randym     6.380000   0.530000   6.910000 (  7.520760)
eric       7.730000   0.680000   8.410000 (  9.135986)
santhosh   5.530000   0.460000   5.990000 (  6.518203)
---------------------------------- total: 29.180000sec

               user     system      total        real
long       7.000000   0.740000   7.740000 (  8.349310)
randym     6.260000   0.540000   6.800000 (  7.426409)
eric       7.630000   0.590000   8.220000 (  8.882282)
santhosh   5.550000   0.460000   6.010000 (  6.736294)
```

Ruby 2.1.2
Mac Book Pro (2013)
3 GHz Intel Core i7
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: Well, with all due respect, @Santhosh's solution does not return the expected data structure :-D

Comment: well spotted, sir! Editing to include to_a

Comment: @EricPlaton Nice catch. I've corrected it now. -- Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
items = [[60, 3], [60, 3], [276, 2], [276, 2], [48, 2], [207, 2], [46, 2],
 [60, 2], [280, 2], [207, 1], [48, 1], [112, 1], [60, 1], [207, 1], [112, 1],
 [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [48, 1], [276, 1], [276, 1], [278, 1], [46, 1],
 [48, 1], [279, 1], [207, 1]]

hash = Hash.new(0)
items.each do |item|
  hash[item[0]] += item[1]
end

hash
{60=>9, 276=>8, 48=>6, 207=>5, 46=>3, 280=>2, 112=>2, 278=>1, 279=>1}

hash.to_a
[[60, 9], [276, 8], [48, 6], [207, 5], [46, 3], [280, 2], [112, 2], [278, 1], [279, 1]]
```